# Does a system of non-homogeneous first-order linear differential equations (consisting of two equations) always have a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The system of non-homogeneous first-order linear differential equations which I am referring to has the following form:
\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
        x' = ax' + by' + f(t)  \\
        y' = cx' + dy' + g(t)  \\
        x(0) = x_0 , y(0) = y_0
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
with t is a real number.
Does a system of non-homogeneous first-order linear differential equations (consisting of two equations) always have a solution? If it does not always have a solution, what are the conditions for $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ for them to have a solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant a system in which there are no $\prime$ symbols on the right side.Basically the answer is "yes." Here is how to get started. Write the system as $$\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime}\\y^{\prime}\end{bmatrix}=M\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}f(t)\\g(t)\end{bmatrix}$$Make the change of variables $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}$$ where $P$ is a real non-singular 2x2 matrix.Then $$\begin{bmatrix}u^{\prime}\\v^{\prime}\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}MP\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}+P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}f(t)\\g(t)\end{bmatrix}$$P can be chosen so that one of 3 things occurs.(i) $P^{-1}MP$ is diagonal $$\text{(ii)}\space P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda &1\\0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$ $$\text{(iii)}P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha &-\beta\\\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix}, \beta \ne 0$$. In all 3 cases, it is fairly easy to write out the solution explicitly, provided $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ can be integrated.

Comment: I am thinking of the case where f(t) or g(t) is discontinuous at 0 . Does it still has a solution in this case?